# PHP Connection with interbase

Tags: php, interbase

I am trying to connect php with interbase. It seems php only works with firebird, instead of interbase.  I already have a database , that is created in interbase, I just need connectivity with interbase, not firebird. When I am trying to connect it with interbase, it says .. invalid database. where as connection with firebird database is working fine. Using php 5.6, windows server, 64 bit architechture

Answer (score 0):

There's a ton of helpful comments at the [ibase_connect function page over at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-connect.php), are you sure that you're following through and checking version numbers? It appears that you may need to perform a manual fix and set the dialect version of the connection, as follows:

`ibase_connect ('localhost:/usr/db/db.gdb', 'SYSDBA', 'masterkey', 'ISO8859_1', '100', '1' ) ;`

The last 1 as a parameter resets the dialect mode between the ibase_connect() and Interbase. You also should check and see if the version of PHP you're running is compatible with the version of Interbase you're running.

Comment: ibase_connect(): Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.. I stopped firebird server and started interbase server. Here too php goes for firebird login. php 5.6 is 32 bit, interbase is 32 bit and firebird is 32 bit. Windows machine is 64 bit   . 
interbase
Firebird/InterBase Support dynamic/n
Compile-time Client Library Version Firebird API version 25/n
Run-time Client Library Version WI-V6.3.7.27050 Firebird 2.5